# jquery works on its own, but fires only once inside js

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

this jquery (just below), which hides columns in tables based on dropdown selection, works. (Shoutout to the member called Oka, whose help with this code was hugely appreciated.). However it works fully only in stand-alone documents.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sel').on('change', function () {
        var val = $(this).val(),
        target = '.' + val;
        $('.choice').hide();
        $(target).show();
    }).change();
});
```

But it works only partially when I put the tables inside another (javascript-enabled) document.

i.e., you load that document in a browser, and the tables display as they should -- with several columns hidden. However, the dropdown select in each of the tables (which is supposed to show one column of class='choice x' while hiding the others) does not fire hide/show. You can select from the dropdown but the table just sits there showing/hiding the same column(s) as it did when the page loaded.

I googled this and found things similar in stackoverflow, from which I gather that it's some timing issue, and/or my "event hander" is not set up correctly.

But beyond that I'm stumped. Any suggestions on how to get unstuck?

(Because the "outer" js document from which these tables load appears to not be the issue -- it's allowing the above jquery to run albeit only once -- I thought I'd leave that code out.)

okay, by popular demand I'll post the (uuuuugly) outer document. Bear in mind it works with a separate js file, which I'll also post.

The jquery above is in the file 'dropdown.js'.

Outer document:

```
<?php
include ("file1.php");
include ("file2.php");
$tt = "<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Outer table</TITLE>
<STYLE>
.conts  {visibility:hidden}
.tab    {   border-top:solid thin #E0E0E0;
            border-right:solid thin gray;
            border-left:solid thin #E0E0E0;
            background: #C0C0C0;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:10pt;
            text-align:center;
            font-weight:normal
            display: inline-block;
            background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #CCFF66 50%, #CCFF99 100%);
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #CCFF66 50%, #CCFF99 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CCFF66 50%, #CCFF99 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CCFF66 50%, #CCFF99 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #CCFF66 50%, #CCFF99 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 1px 0 #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #FFF;
    margin: 0 -5px;
    padding: 0 20px;}

.selTab {   border-left:solid thin white;
            border-top:solid thin white;
            border-right:solid thin black;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:10pt;
            width: 10;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center}

</STYLE>
<SCRIPT src = 'tabview.js'></SCRIPT>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<SCRIPT src = 'dropdown.js'></SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR=white onclick='changeTabs()' onload='init()'>


<DIV STYLE='position:absolute; top:10; height:350; width:300; left:25; border:none thin gray'>


<TABLE STYLE='width:108%; height:250' CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
    <TR>
        <TD ID=t1 CLASS=selTab HEIGHT=25>Point</TD>
        <TD ID=t2 CLASS=tab  >Lifecycle</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD ID=t1base STYLE='height:2; border-left:solid thin white'></TD>
        <TD ID=t2base STYLE='height:2; background-color:white'></TD>
        <TD ID=t3base STYLE='height:2; background-color:white'></TD>
        <TD ID=t4base STYLE='height:2; background-color:white'></TD>
        <TD ID=t5base STYLE='height:2; background-color:white'></TD>
        <TD ID=t6base STYLE='height:2; background-color:white'></TD>
        <TD ID=t7base STYLE='height:2; background-color:white; border-right:solid thin white'></TD> 
    </TR>


    <TR>
        <TD ID=tabContents>sample contents</TD>

    </TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>


<DIV CLASS=conts ID=t1Contents>$t_file1</DIV>
<DIV CLASS=conts ID=t2Contents>$t_file2</DIV>";
?>
</BODY>
<?php   $tt.="</HTML>";
echo $tt;
?>
```

And here is the javascript file ('tabview.js') that the outer document refers to:

```
//a public function that the container uses to pass in values for the labels
function public_Labels(label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7){

    t1.innerText = label1;
    t2.innerText = label2;
    t3.innerText = label3;
    t4.innerText = label4;
    t5.innerText = label5;
  t6.innerText = label6;
  t7.innerText = label7;
 }

//a public function that the container uses to pass in values for the card containers
function public_Contents(contents1, contents2, contents3, contents4, contents5, contents6, contents7){

   t1Contents.innerHTML = contents1;
   t2Contents.innerHTML = contents2;
   t3Contents.innerHTML = contents3;
   t4Contents.innerHTML = contents4;
   t5Contents.innerHTML = contents5;
   t6Contents.innerHTML = contents6;
   t7Contents.innerHTML = contents7;

   init();
}

//sets the default display to tab 1
function init(){
tabContents.innerHTML = t1Contents.innerHTML;
}   

//this is the tab switching function
var currentTab;
var tabBase;
var firstFlag = true;


function changeTabs(){

   if(firstFlag == true){
    currentTab = t1;
    tabBase = t1base;
    firstFlag = false;
    }

    if(window.event.srcElement.className == 'tab'){

    currentTab.className = 'tab';

    tabBase.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

    currentTab = window.event.srcElement;

    tabBaseID = currentTab.id + 'base';

    tabContentID = currentTab.id + 'Contents';

    tabBase = document.all(tabBaseID);

    tabContent = document.all(tabContentID);

    currentTab.className = 'selTab';

    tabBase.style.backgroundColor = '';

       tabContents.innerHTML = tabContent.innerHTML;

    }
}
```

Comment: well... this can happen due to various reasons... did you include jquery? pls show us the outer document, or theres nothing we can do.

Comment: okay, took your advice and posted it. Sorry about the dog's breakfast that was posted initially... I hadn't figured out how to get around the 4-space rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding the .on event to ("#sel"), which doesn't exist yet in your second document. Change the .on to listen to the root, and pass #sel as a selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#sel', function () {
        var val = $(this).val(),
        target = '.' + val;
        $('.choice').hide();
        $(target).show();
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: okay, very nice -- this does most of the work. It hides the columns when a dropdown option is selected. But when the page initially loads, all columns display. The original jquery hid the right columns when the page loaded (which I want) but did nothing when the dropdown options were selected.